# ng-submit called twice in angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have gone through several questions regarding this issue, but none solved my issue

I am using a form in which **two submit type button calling same function**. One button is send an extra variable with it on ng-click. when I submit my function is being called twice.

I am using an approach told in the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025618/how-to-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-a-form-using-angular-js) (mostly voted)

*I have not included controller as ng-controller in HTML*

```
<form ng-submit="SaveContent(Form)">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Data.IsSent = true">Save & Send</button>
</form>
```

How to handle this issue ?

Comment: No enough information to answer.

Comment: @dfsq What more information required ?

Comment: The question that you refer to does not have two buttons with type='submit'. One is a simple button. Try changing that.

Comment: Code worked fine fine after hard refreshing browser and re-starting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular form [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action) specifies it as

> if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or
>   input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields will
>   trigger the click handler on the first button or input[type=submit]
>   (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit)

I inserted your code in below example and it behaves exactly like it is specified in the docs and only one submit (the first) is executed when submitting the form

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

$scope.Data ={};
$scope.Data.IsSent = false;
$scope.SaveContent = function(form){
if($scope.Data.IsSent){
  alert('submitted- and ngclick is invoked');
  }else{
  alert('submitted');
  }
  $scope.Data.IsSent = false;
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form ng-submit="SaveContent(Form)">
    <input type="text" name="text1"/>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Data.IsSent = true">Save & Send</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and it took me 5 days to figure it out. Do not add (ngSubmit) in the opening tag of the form.

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete. If the `ng-submit` is removed, that functionality needs to be moved to the buttons. Could you share some example code to make this answer more useful?